# What does the meaning of the phrase "couldn't be more"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have a question about the word "optimistic" from the Peter Klein's resignation letter. He wrote:

> One noteworthy characteristic of Finance is the regularity of its
>   rhythm – month end, quarter end, year end. Every one of those
>   milestones marks the passage of time. And as time passes, and
>   milestones are marked, we all periodically reflect on our lives, our
>   goals, and our priorities. As we approach the end of the fiscal year,
>   I have been reflecting in that way. And I have decided that now is a
>   good time for me to step away from Microsoft and take some time to
>   spend with my family in a way that I haven't had the opportunity to do
>   in the 30 years I have been working.
>
> This has not been an easy decision. I love Microsoft. I love my job.
>   When I joined Microsoft 11 years ago I had this loosely held belief
>   that people were one of the most important elements of any job or any
>   company. I had no idea how profoundly true that is, but I do now.
>   People are everything. Microsoft is the most amazing collection of
>   talented, passionate and caring people I could ever imagine being
>   associated with. It's been an honor and my good fortune to have been
>   part of that.
>
> I am proud of the work that Finance has done and the impact we have
>   had on the Company. One reason that now is a good time to leave is
>   that the organization is very strong, and I am delighted we will be
>   naming an internal candidate. **I couldn't be more optimistic about both
>   the Company's and Finance's future.**
>
> Looking ahead, I have no specific plans. In the short term I will work
>   to ensure a smooth transition. After that I intend to spend time with
>   my extended family which is dispersed throughout the country and
>   hopefully get to some long deferred travel. For the last 11 years
>   Microsoft has been my family and now I am going to focus on my other
>   family.
>
> Thanks for being such a great team – I will follow your success with
>   great interest and pride.
>
> Peter

From my understanding, the word "optimistic" mean to expect that a good thing will happen in the future. But from the bold sentence, it sounds like he doesn't hope that good things will happen at Microsoft.

Comment: Your presumed meaning of _optimistic_ is correct. If I were to guess, I'd say that this question is more about the _couldn't be more_ construct than it is about the definition of the word _optimistic_. Indeed, the speaker wishes only goodwill on the company, and expects that the company will remain successful.

Comment: @J.R. I agree with you. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It means the same as it normally means.  In the phrase "couldn't be more" optimistic, it means that he is as optimistic as he could possibly be - that they will do well.  He couldn't expect that they will do well any more than he already does.